# Error while connecting to remote database server from container

Tags: mysql, docker, go

I have a service deployed in mesos, which queries a remote database server. I used [`github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`](http://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) to query the database from my Go code. It was working fine for about a week. But today I got this error: `driver: bad connection`

So I entered the docker container where my service runs and type in command line:

```
mysql -uxxx -hx.x.x.x -Pxxx -Dxxx -pxxx
```

Here's the response:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

This is the content of /etc/mysql/my.cnf file:

```
[mysql]
no-auto-rehash  # Faster start of mysql but no tab completition
```

What can be the error here? And how can I solve this?

Edit: When I run the same command from my local machine it works fine. I can query the database from the command line of my pc.

Comment: What do the container logs say?

Comment: Last time I got `reading initial communication packet`, it's firewall issue on database server, my company IT enable hardware firewall at that time.

Comment: @atline Edited the question. I can access the remote database from my local machine. Can it still be a firewall issue?

Comment: I suggest you do next experiments to narrow down issue: 1) from container visit another mysql container which in the same network namespace 2) from container visit a mysql container which on the docker host 3) from container visit another external mysql service. Such kinds of problem I guess really not easy to find root cause if not make experiments...